# box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px white not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

```
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px white;
```

This is working fine in IE9, FF and chrome. But in IE8 its not working I need to have sunken border

[image]

I need to get the border as in above image. This is not working in IE8. I have tried this code

```
filter:
 progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=0, Color='white'),
 progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=90, Color='white'),
 progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=180, Color='white'),
 progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=270, Color='white');
```

The above code uses shadow for IE8 with strength and direction but when I use this am not 
getting the desired output. I had also used `Microsoft.Glow` and `Microsoft.Dropshadow` both these properties also not working. When I apply this code its applying to all 4 sides of a cell but I need only for top and left corner of a cell.

Comment: check the direction, you need to remove two progid filter

Answer (score 1):

Lets use this code?

```
body{background:black;}
div {
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #ffffff;
    background:aqua;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
filter: 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=0,strength=5), 
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=270,strength=5);

}
```

Comment: yes this code is working but its hiding the cell border

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/jfRDA/div {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #999;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    padding: 10px;
}<div>
    Love or not! I am a developer
</div>